# what does non-interactive command line tool means?

Tags: linux, wget

Guys im researching about WGET command in linux, (im very new to linux) and i found this statement which i dont understand

*GNU Wget is a free software package for retrieving files using HTTP, HTTPS and FTP, the most widely-used Internet protocols. It is a non-interactive commandline tool, so it may easily be called from scripts, cron jobs, terminals without X-Windows support, etc.*

and what does

*"without X-windows support means"* too?

Also what i understand about wget is that it downloads something, but how come i can

```
wget http://google.com/
```

and see some weird text in the screen.

A little help here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wget downloads content to a file. So the text you see in your terminal is just a job log.

Non interactive means that it doesn't prompt for any input while it works. You specify everything via command line parameters.

X (and related) handles GUI rendering. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System for details.

Answer (score 0):

easier to think of what wget DOESN'T do. Your typical browser reads a URL from a GUI interface, and when you click on it, the browser generates & sends a file request to retrieve an HTML file. It then translates the (text based) html source file, sends further requests for content like images etc., and renders the whole thing to GUI as a webpage.

Wget just sends the request & dowloads the file.  It can be controlled to recursively fetch links in the source file, so you could download the whole internet with a few keystrokes XD.

It's useful by itself for grabbing graphic & audio files without having to sit through a point & click session.  You can also pipe the html source through a custom sed or perl filter to extract data.  (like going to the city transit page & converting schedule info to a spreadsheet format)